# Configuring php mail() per domain

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have about 6 sites on my dedicated server (running centos5), and all emails sent using php's mail function are sent by nobody@servername.hostname.com e.g. "Received: from nobody by servername.hostname.com with local (Exim 4.69)". Is there any way to change this to show the appropriate domain?

Comment: You could use header rewriting but that will not work as all mail is being submitted by the same user (nobody)

Answer (score 7):

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for `mail()`:

*Note: When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.*

Like most php.ini settings this can overridden in the vhost config on Apache or via .htaccess or it can be set in the script (optionaly using auto_prepend) and since 5.3.0 via [.user.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) files. But rather than explicitly setting the From, Reply-To and Return-path headers, it's simpler to just specify the recipient when the 'sendmail' program is invoked to process the message.

Assuming exim uses the standard flags on the commandline for its sendmail cli:

in php.ini:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -ffrom@example.com -t -i"
```

In httpd.conf

```
php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -ffrom@example.com -t -i"
```

In .htaccess.conf

```
php_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -ffrom@example.com -t -i"
```

(note your sendmail path may be different from that shown)

C.

Comment: This is incorrect - you can't set sendmail_path per domain, it's systemwide: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: @Farkie are you sure? `PHP_INI_SYSTEM Entry can be set in php.ini or httpd.conf` <http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php>. For example default DirectAdmin vhost templates set the from field via sendmail_path in each vhost section of httpd.conf.

Comment: That means it can't be set in `.htaccess`, which isn't named `.htaccess.conf` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some wrapper script, for example my [php-secure-sendmail](http://www.marki-online.net/php-secure-sendmail/). It allows you to log every sent email (virtualhost,date/time,recipient), limit number of sent emails per hour/day by virtualhost, set envelope-sender and many more...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to overwrite the value only with **php_admin_value** in the apache site conf.
It can`t be set with php_value

Answer (score -1):

You must use the -f option of [php mail function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).